# Attempting to build RQB from source getting assert error from testJsList

Tags: redquerybuilder

LOVE RQB!!, I want to get the source building. I have cloned the repo with git and I believe I have downloaded and have all of the bits installedbut when I run "mvn clean install" it goes through some machinations, then finally fails with the following

```
Failed tests: 
[INFO]   testJsList(com.redspr.redquerybuilder.js.client.GwtTestBasics)
```

Here is the output from the stack:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.325 sec <<<  FAILURE!
[INFO] testJsList(com.redspr.redquerybuilder.js.client.GwtTestBasics)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <<< FAILURE!
[INFO] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Remote test failed at 127.0.0.1 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
[INFO] expected: <22>, actual: <14>
[INFO]  at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:193)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:198)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:94)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:43)
[INFO]  at com.redspr.redquerybuilder.js.client.GwtTestBasics.testJsList(GwtTestBasics.java:192)
[INFO]  at com.redspr.redquerybuilder.js.client.__GwtTestBasics_unitTestImpl.doRunTest(__GwtTestBasics_unitTestImpl.java:7)
[INFO]  at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:62)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runBare(GWTTestCase.java:188)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.__doRunTest(GWTTestCase.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.runTest(GWTRunner.java:390)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.doRunTest(GWTRunner.java:318)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner.access$9(GWTRunner.java:312)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner$TestBlockListener.onSuccess(GWTRunner.java:107)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.junit.client.impl.GWTRunner$TestBlockListener.onSuccess(GWTRunner.java:1)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:249)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Please could you try: mvn clean install -DskipTests=true to see if that builds you working code? Could just be weird test issue. Either way please could you raise an issue on github with details of your environment?

Comment: Looks like that works for the build.  TYVM.  I will open an issue on github.  As a side note, the pom.xml files do not work with gwt 2.6.0 (You have to use 2.5.1), as there is an issue with missing "runTarget" in the configuration section of the pom.xml, works fine in 2.5.1 though.

Comment: Glad that worked. Please could you raise an issue for GWT 2.6.0 and maybe a pull request?  I'm a bit bogged down trying to add the vistor pattern for validation and/or custom serialisation.

Comment: Yup NP.  Will get to that today.  I'm also geektravels :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the unit test of RedQueryBuilder 0.6.0 due to the unit test setting the time in UTC then testing the days, hours, minutes are the same in local time... Only true in the UK and Lisbon :( Fix should be in 0.7.0. Thanks for finding and raising the bug.

Comment: Yup got fixed in the latest release, tyvm.